# Non-greedy regex not working

Tags: regular-expressions, isearch, characters

I can't seem to get the non-greedy regex to work.

## Sample String:

```
ABCD，E《F》、《GH》、《XYIJ》、《KL》、《MN》。
```

## Regex Code:

```
《.+?IJ》
```

## Search Result:

[image: regex search result]

Because `.+?` is a non-greedy input, I was expecting the search to confine to the nearest `《》` pair, as shown below.

The present output is no different from searching this:

```
《.+IJ》
```

Which essentially makes the non-greedy code redundant.

## Expected Result:

[image: expected result]

How should we get the non-greedy function to work as expected?

Comment: "The present output is no different from searching this: `《.+IJ》`" -- that is because you have exactly *one* instance of `IJ》` in the line.  Add additional instances, and you will observe how greedy vs non-greedy quantifiers work.

Comment: If it helps, note that the `《` has *already* been matched before you begin matching the non-greedy expression. The latter says to find the smallest match for `.+` to get from the existing `《` to an instance of `IJ》`.  If it can match the entire expression from that initial `《` then it's a good match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not about using non-greedy matching.  It is about which chars you're matching.  Specifically, you want to match `《` followed by any number of **non-`《`** chars, followed by `IJ》`.

This is a regexp that finds that: **`《[^《]+IJ》`**.

This is a typical operation, for searching text that has paired delimiters.  For example, you do the same thing when searching for a string: `"[^"]*"`.

---

Or if you also want to deal with char escaping,
`"\([^"]\|\\\(.\|\n\)\)*"`.

That matches either any char other than `"` (**`[^"]`**), or (**`\|`**) a backslash (**`\\`**) followed by any character.  The "any character" part is (**`\(.\|\n\)`**, that is, either any char except newline (**`.`**) or a newline char (**`\n`**). The final **`*`** says match zero or more such things.

(And don't forget that if you use a regexp in a Lisp string you need to double the backslashes - not shown here. See [Syntax for Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-for-Strings.html).)

Comment: Your answer and explanation is clear an concise. But I find the character escaping example given totally confusing. Would appreciate if you could say something more about the way this regex is constructed and the reason why.

Comment: I added some explanation. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I will give the same answer as @Drew, but phrased a little differently.

Your expression 《.+IJ》will match the first 《, then will match the minimum number of characters (because of the ?) until the IJ》 sequence.

You cannot use the "non-greediness" of the ? to un-match the first matching 《 in order to find a later one.

An expression you can use to do what you want is what Drew said:

《[^《]+IJ》

This will match a 《, then at least one non-《 character, then IJ, then the closing 》.  For this problem, you don't need a non-greedy modifier.