# Non-greedy regex group

Tags: regular-expressions

This is related to my previous question over [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/54612/23726).

```el
(replace-regexp "\\(\\[\\[\\)\\(zotero:.+\\]\\)\\(\\[.+，[《〈][^《〈]+[》〉]\\)?.+。\\(\\]\\]\\)" "\\1cite-\\2\\3\\4，頁")
```

I'd like to use the above code to shorten Chinese citation strings to `author，title，page` format.

---

## Sample Data

*Original String*:

`[[zotero://select/items/1_P36Y9V2B][周東平，〈《晉書·刑法志》校注舉隅〉，《中國古代法律文獻研究》，2016年，00期。]]`

*Expected Result (shortened string)*:

`[[cite-zotero://select/items/1_P36Y9V2B][周東平，〈《晉書·刑法志》校注舉隅〉]]，頁`

---

The code snippet `[《〈][^《]+[》〉]` correctly restricts the search to a single title element between `，`s.

[image]

When joined with `.+，`, however, it fails to be non-greedy and ends up picking up both article title (between `〈〉`s)  and journal title (between `《》`s) at the same time.

[image]

This results in a shortened citation which is lengthier than expected.

```
[[cite-zotero://select/items/1_P36Y9V2B][周東平，〈《晉書·刑法志》校注舉隅〉，《中國古代法律文獻研究》]]，頁
```

[image]

How do we make `\\3` non-greedy, as expected?

---

## Update:

I just realize this could be an issue specific to the data string listed above, i.e.:

`周東平，〈《晉書·刑法志》校注舉隅〉，《中國古代法律文獻研究》，2016年，00期。`

Somehow, the `《晉書·刑法志》` nested in `《晉書·刑法志》校注舉隅〉` complicated matters.

Other simpler, but similarly structured data such as this worked as expected:

`[[zotero://select/items/1_97XVI66Q][金春峯，〈周官之社會行政組織〉，收入《周官之成書及其反映的文化與時代新考》台北：東大，1993年。]]`

*Result*:

`[[cite-zotero://select/items/1_97XVI66Q][金春峯，〈周官之社會行政組織〉]]，頁`

Comment: Both have already been listed above in the original post.

Comment: Oh - I get what you mean. Question has been edited to reflect the actual string behind the org-mode link display that is to be processed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters the non-greedy quantifiers are `??`, `+?`, and `*?`, and so you haven't specified any non-greedy matching in that regexp.

---

I **strongly** recommend using <kbd>M-x</kbd> `re-builder` to visualise what is going on (it will show each group in a different colour).

---

Looking at part of your regexp, this:

```
, [《〈][^《〈]+[》〉]
```

matches a comma and a space, followed by either `《` or `〈`, followed by one-or-more characters *not* in that set, and finally either `》` or `〉`

In the case of:

```
, 〈《晉書·刑法志》校注舉隅〉，《中國古代法律文獻研究》
```

The pattern does **not** match the start of that string because after `, 〈` we have a character which fails to match `[^《〈]` (because it *is* one of those two characters).  Consequently that part of the regexp does not match the text until the *second* comma.

This 'works' overall because you had `.+` preceding that in the pattern, so that simply extends to match everything up to that second comma.  If you change that `.+` into `\\(.+\\)` in re-builder, you'll see what it is matching.

---

Try the following in re-builder:

```
"\\(\\[\\[\\)\\(zotero:.+\\]\\)\\(\\[\\(.+?\\)，\\(《.+?》\\|〈.+?〉\\)\\)?\\(.+\\)。\\(\\]\\]\\)"
```

I've added several extra groups so you can see exactly what each bit matches.

I recommend that you spend a bit of time experimenting with that.

The *key* difference to your original pattern is this:

```
\\(《.+?》\\|〈.+?〉\\)
```

in place of:

```
[《〈][^《〈]+[》〉]
```

This approach works for the examples you have shown.

If you have any titles containing newlines then you would need to use `\\(?:.\\|\n\\)+?` instead of `.+?` because `.` does not match newlines.  Or you could alternatively use:

```
\\(《[^》]+》\\|〈[^〉]+〉\\)
```

(Which isn't *exactly* the same thing, but would most likely be equivalent for your purposes, and is probably what you were meaning to express in the first instance.)